# How to construct a line from points in pyshp?

Tags: python, polygon, pyshp

I am reading a shapefile for a pipeline and what I've noticed is that if I just draw a line from one point to the next (in the order I read them), there will be points where the line terminates, and the next point is really a new line - but I can't see any way to tell where those points are...  How does that work?

Comment: Can you expand upon your question to include code samples, screenshots, sample data, etc? Also please try to describe the problem you are having more clearly, it's a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: is there a field in the shapefile that has a pipeline segment number?

Comment: Not to sure how to accomplish this, but due to your question I discovered pyshp which is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but what the heck :P

If a row contains multiple new/disconnected lines as you suggested you can find the index positions where "the next point is really a new line" by calling the `shape.parts` attribute. Note that if there is only one line then the indexlist from shape.parts will still list the first point, ie `[0]`.

Check out the Pyshp docs for more on how to use it: http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/wiki/PyShpDocs